How to reconnect MySQL database in Vapor?
I am using Vapor framework form server-side back-end using Swift in Ubuntu. In the 80% project done and this framework not reconnecting database automatically. I just need solution to reconnect database at least manually. In worst time, the database is automatically closed on the client demo. Because of this all my work gone ruin. I tried below but it does not work. I'm really frustrated that without db_reconnect function the whole work and the whole framework is just garbage. I've to move for Laravel.
I've stored the database in a class which is used as common to query from database on the configure.swift
app.databases.use(.mysql(configuration: .prod), as: .mysql)

do {
    
    try await app.db.withConnection({ database in
        
        Database.initialize(database)
    })
    
} catch {
    
    fatalError("Unable to connect database")
}

However, sometimes query result comes with database disconnect error. So, I try to reconnect the database with same db which is initialized previously. I've got Connected printed in the console continuously which means the db is actually not connected. That is why it comes to this function after executing some queries.
private func connect_db(_ completionHandler:@escaping(Error?) -> Void){
    print("Reconnecting Database....")
    if let db = self.db as? FluentKit.Database {
        
        Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
            
            do {
                 
                try await db.withConnection({ _ in
                    
                    print("Connected")
                    completionHandler(nil)
                })
                
            } catch {
                
                print("Unable to connect!")
                completionHandler(error)
            }
        }
       
    } else {
        
        completionHandler(SERVER_ERROR("Invalid DB", info: "The Database isn't Database object", code: 28))
    }
}

Try 2:
private func connect_db(_ completionHandler:@escaping(Error?) -> Void){
    print("Reconnecting Database....")
    
    Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
      
        do  {
         
            try await kAPI.app.db.withConnection { database in
                
                Database.initialize(database)
                print("Connected")
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
            
        } catch {
            
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    }
}

I've used connect_db on this function
func query(_ query: String, with continuation: CheckedContinuation<[MySQLRow]?, Error>) {
     
    self.db.query(query).whenComplete { result in
        
        switch result {
            
        case .success(let rows):
            if rows.isEmpty {
                continuation.resume(returning: nil)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: rows)
            }
            
        case .failure(let error):
            
            let error = error as NSError
            
            print("Error: \(error)")
            if error.code == 11 { // Disconnected
                
                self.connect_db { error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                        
                    } else {
                         
                        self.query(query, with: continuation)
                    }
                }
                 
            } else {
                
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}

Update:
Vapor Doesn't have solution at all. I've moved to use Laravel Framework.
WARNING: Don't stick with immature framework and some corporate fanboys promoted frameworks. If so most possibly you could end up with ruin the work, time and money.
How can I fix this issue?

I have never had a database disconnect on me in all the time I have been using Vapor. This is my standard connection code:
func configureDatabase(_ app: Application) throws {
    guard let DBHost = Environment.get(C.Env.DBHostname),
          let DBAccount = Environment.get(C.Env.DBAccount),
          let DBPassword = Environment.get(C.Env.DBPassword),
          let DBDatabase = app.environment == .testing ?
          Environment.get(C.Env.DBTestDatabase) : Environment.get(C.Env.DBDatabase)
    else { throw InternalError.misc() }

    var tlsConfiguration = TLSConfiguration.makeClientConfiguration()
    tlsConfiguration.certificateVerification = .none
    app.databases.use(.mysql(hostname: DBHost, username: DBAccount, password: DBPassword, database: DBDatabase,
                             tlsConfiguration: tlsConfiguration), as: .mysql)
    app.databases.default(to: .mysql)
}


I tested this code with manually terminating database connection. This code doesn't reconnect to the database automatically either no way to reconnect again with new database without closing the terminatted database session. Thank you for your time.
